# holomorphic map from projective space into a complex torus is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

What I attempted:
I know a holomorphic map is open so the image is open and closed (as a compact subset of separable space), so it's surjective.
Then I'm stuck to show there is no branched covering from a sphere to a torus. Any hints are appreciated.

A follow up question: how about a holomorphic map from $\mathbb{P}^n$ to the complex torus?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/9090/450

Comment: thanks! Feel sorry for my poor algebraic topology.